# Macro to repeat almost the same code

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have to write same code dependent on compile time constant parameter, something like:

```
map["text 0"] = vec[0];
map["text 1"] = vec[1];
...
map["text n"] = vec[n];
```

The problem is that I don't know `n` when I'm writing the code, I receive it as template parameter. The obvious solution is to use one loop and generate the `"text k"` inside the loop and use `vec[k]`, but this has runtime overhead when it should be done at compile time. Another solution would be to specialize the function for different `N` values, but in this way I'll have to write same code by hand multiple times and there is no reason to make it template.

I know there are some smart macros that can repeat similar things N times(like `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` macro family), but I can't find one solution for my specific problem.

Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: @jrok Yes, but not all features(VS2010 and latest Xcode)

Comment: Templates and a loop could probably be optimised by the compiler.

Comment: What is `vec` and what is `map` ? (just to be clear) and could you write an example of the function that you intend the use so that we have a starting point in our reflexion; because at the moment, I am afraid it's not so clear :x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have really, *really* tight performance constraints, there is no reason to worry about the run-time overhead. Insertions are going to be performed at run-time anyway, and insertion time is definitely going to dominate the time required to change a character in a string.

Moreover, macros are hard to debug and to maintain: avoid them if possible. Here, I would suggest to unroll a simple loop:

```
std::string s = "text 0";
std::map<std::string, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    m[s] = vec[i];
    s[5] = '1' + i; // This is going to be the run-time overhead...
}
```

If your numbers grow higher than `9`, in C++11 you could use the `to_string()` function for converting an integer into a string:

```
std::string const s = "text ";
std::map<std::string, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    m[s + std::to_string(i)] = vec[i];
}
```

*If performance will prove to be an issue*, then you can try a more hardcore approach based on macros. However, if your measurements won't indicate a significant overhead, **prefer simplicity and clarity** and unroll a simple loop.

Comment: This will trigger undefined behavior, I can't modify a const char* - "text 0" is const char* even if it's not declared as const.

Comment: @Felics: The string literal `"text 0"` has type `const char []`, but that's what you are using to initialize an array of `char`, which is modifiable. You are not modifying the original literal, so no UB here. And if your pattern is more complex, you can use `std::string`.

Comment: Even if you declare it as non const, there is a conversion from const to non const(accepted by 2003 standard, not accepted by 2011 standard). Also N can have more than one digit.

Comment: @Felics: It is perfectly valid to initialize a const with _a copy of_ a non-const. E.g. `int a = 5; const int b = a;`.

Comment: @MFelics: I am not doing `char s* = "Hello"`, which is probably what you refer to. Here I am doing a copy of "Hello" into the array. And again, if the pattern is more complicated, use `std::string`. This is unlikely to become a sensible overhead at run-time.

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes, my bad:) Event if your answer solves the problem, I still want to wait for a compile time variant(this is very efficient, but it's the first solution I proposed in the question).

Comment: @AndyProwl: I would recommend using `std::string s` anyway (and maybe `std::string const s` in the latter case). I see no (significant) gain in using `char s[]` and many issues could crop up during maintenance...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: In the first example I was just trying to avoid the run-time heap allocation that would be required to initialize an `std::string`, which could bring some performance loss if the function is part of a critical loop. In the second example yes, probably using a (`const`) `std::string` makes more sense. Thank you for that

Comment: @Felics: Yes, I noticed that you already proposed this as a solution. My answer is mainly to tell you that the solution you proposed made sense, and that you should not do premature optimization. Unless you have a reason to care about performance, always choose the simplest solution.

Comment: @AndyProwl Usually I ask to find out if it's possible or not. Every question gives me new insights of different problems. I have already implemented this solution(not as efficient as here, so it's a win!).

Comment: @AndyProwl: But a `std::string` is created anyway when you insert in the map, so the gain is minor...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That's true, you convinced me. I will edit the answer, thank you

Comment: @Felics: Fair enough :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp> 
//... or just the required sub-headers

// Will generate code for 0, 1, ... (N_END - 1)
#define N_END 10

#define ONE_ASSIGNMENT(maZ, maIter, maData) \
    if (maIter <= n) map["text " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(maIter)] = vec[maIter];

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(N_END, ONE_ASSIGNMENT, %%) //this generates the code

#undef ONE_ASSIGNMENT
#undef N_END
```

Note that the `if()` compares a literal to a template parameter (`n`), so any optimiser worth its salt will generate branchless code from this.

I use `%%` as "this value is never used." It's passed into the `maData` argument, so if you'd have something useful to actually pass (such as `"text "`), you can do it instead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yup. That's fine. I am even relying on this to make the optimiser turn the `if()` into just the body or a `nop`, since it knows both the literal (`maIter`) and the compile-time constant (`n`) involved in the condition. Of course, the code would also work without the optimisation (but it's really just compile-time condition elimination).

Comment: Then I don't quite understand why the `<= n`, should not it be `== n` ? (I am not sure I understood the question anwyay...)

Comment: @MatthieuM. The way I understand the question (I admit it could be clearer) is that `doTheWork<n>` should set entries 0, 1, ... n. That's what the code in my answer does, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Repetition does not seem a problem to me, but compile-time conversion of int to string and subsequent concatenation does. The repetition problem can be solved along the following technique (untested):

```
template<k,l> struct fill_vector {
    static void doIt (... & vec) {
        vec [INT_TO_TEXT (k)] = k;
        fill_vector<k+1,l-1>::doIt (vec);
    }
};

template<k> struct fill_vector<k,0> {
    static void doIt (... & vec) {
        vec [INT_TO_TEXT (k)] = k;
    }
};

//...

fill_vector<0,n>::doIt (vec);
```

Maybe somebody has an idea how to implement `INT_TO_TEXT`